# How to read a trend data with an interval of 10 years into time series?

Tags: r, time-series

This is the data frame.

```
Year <- c(1901, 1911, 1921, 1931, 1941, 1951) 
Population <- c(28445, 346222, 381046, 445606, 512069, 577635)
census <- cbind(Year, Population)
census <- as.data.frame(census)
census
Year    Population
1 1901      28445
2 1911     346222
3 1921     381046
4 1931     445606
5 1941     512069
6 1951     577635
```

And I want it to change to time series data.

```
census.ts <- ts(census)
census.ts
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 6 
Frequency = 1 
Year Population
1 1901      28445
2 1911     346222
3 1921     381046
4 1931     445606
5 1941     512069
6 1951     577635
```

The time interval is 10 years and it seems the above code is not reading the time series data accurately. How do I resolve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
census.ts <- ts(census$Population, start = 1901, deltat = 10)
```

giving:

```
> census.ts
Time Series:
Start = 1901 
End = 1951 
Frequency = 0.1 
[1]  28445 346222 381046 445606 512069 577635
```